# Why does my function not overwrite part of my variable?

Tags: r

I wrote a function that is supposed to count how many NA's there are per column. Before I packed everything into a function it worked. Now it doesn't.

I bet just a stupid beginner mistake, still, I could use your help on this.

My thought is, that the statement

```
x[nrow(x),i] <- aux_count
```

does not properly assign my stuff. Why I wonder.

---

The following code shows, my function, which demonstrates the problem.

```
check_Quandl_tibble <- function(x){
  for(i in 2:ncol(x)){

    aux_count <- 0
    for(j in  1:(nrow(x)-1)){

      if(is.na(x[j,i])){

        aux_count <- aux_count + 1

      }

    }
    x[nrow(x),i] <- aux_count

  }
}
```

```
a <- matrix(c(1,4, NA, 81), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
a <- rbind(a, rep(NA, ncol(a)))
a <- as_tibble(a)

# a now looks like this
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    NA    81     1
2     4    NA    81     1     4
3    NA    81     1     4    NA
4    81     1     4    NA    81
5     1     4    NA    81     1
6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
a <- check_Quandl_tibble(a)

# a now looks like this
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    NA    81     1
2     4    NA    81     1     4
3    NA    81     1     4    NA
4    81     1     4    NA    81
5     1     4    NA    81     1
6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# instead I wanted 
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4    NA    81     1
2     4    NA    81     1     4
3    NA    81     1     4    NA
4    81     1     4    NA    81
5     1     4    NA    81     1
6     1     1     2     1     1 # this row is supposed to count the NA's per column.
```

Answer (score 2):

We can take the `colSums` of logical `matrix` (`is.na(a)`) and `rbind` to the `matrix`

```
rbind(a, colSums(is.na(a)))
```

Here, it is assumed that the 'a' is from the first line of code

```
a <- matrix(c(1,4, NA, 81), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
```

---

If we want to replace the last row after creating the `tibble`

```
a %>% 
  mutate_all(list(~ replace(., n(), sum(is.na(.[-n()])))))
```